# How do I add a panel to Object Properties?

Tags: python, panel

I'm creating an add-on with a custom object. When I select the object, I'd like to be able to edit some custom properties of the object with a small panel. I'd prefer to put it in the object properties menu, here:

[image]

How do I go about creating and adding a panel here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a custom panel you subclass [`bpy.types.Panel`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Panel.html) and set the space, region and context to suit. Setting the space and region to PROPERTIES and WINDOW will place the panel within the properties. Without a context it will show in every section, `object` will place it only in the object properties.

```
class testPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_tester"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = 'object'

    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout.row()
        row.label(text='stuff here')
```