# How to enable or disable panels with the click of a button

Tags: materials, scripting, interface, source-code

[image]

When I click on the "new" button, some panels that were disabled appear. I read their code, but I didn't understand. How do I get certain panels to appear when I click a button?

Comment: Are you trying to make an addon that lets you add your own custom panels to the materials bar? I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, but the location is "VIEW 3D" .. I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's a panels poll method**

The panels are defined and sitting there polling away, waiting to "show".

The poll classmethod of a panel returns true only when the required context (or otherwise related) conditions are met

[Poll method for custom panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82957/poll-method-for-custom-panel)

[Hide Panel With Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/hide-panel-with-python) (*"A Duality Duplicate"*)

In example displayed in question :

(*Speculating haven't checked (...lately), Turn on Developer Extras in settings, so can right click on 99% of UI, view source and see how its done... a common practice is to*)

Have one master materials panel, that always polls.  In this case the material slots, no panel header, has the option to add a material.

All the others seen are , subpanels *ie* Panels with their parent set to the master panel, or others in the space, that have poll requirements met.

In the properties space, there is a sort of "polling" option available by setting `bl_context` of the panel class to match that of the properties space context, matching the 'OBJECT', 'SCENE', 'RENDER' tabs.

[Creating new tabs in properties panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130671/creating-new-tabs-in-properties-panel/130674#130674)

[How do I add a panel to Object Properties?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55627/how-do-i-add-a-subpanel-to-the-object-properties-panel)

These subpanels only poll when there is a `context.material` (In properties space there is a material context member, most likely `context.material == context.object.active_material`

When all the panels require the same poll it is common to see a mixin base class

```
class SomePanelBase:
    bl_context = 'MATERIAL'
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.material is not None
```

And for any defined panel

```
class MaterialFooPanel(SomePanelBase, bpy.types.Panel):
    ...
```

making any such defined panels only display if there is an active material.

Comment: Great! This seems to work as I want ... but, I forgot to mention that the location of my addon is "VIEW_3D" .. Here ```bl_context```  does not work. Would I have to do anything with ```bl_category```?

Comment: NP. `bl_context` is for properties area, leave out otherwise.  `bl_category` is the tab label in other areas.